# marking iCal events as private and sync it with exchange, windows mobile

Tags: data-synchronization, ical, exchange-activesync

I am using Outlook/Exchange at work and iCal at home. I have one Outlook/iCal calender for all my appointments (both home and work). I sync between outlook and iCal using my windows mobile 6.5 phone, currently testing [The Missing Sync](http://www.markspace.com/products/windowsmobile/mac/windows-mobile-sync-software.html).

I need my colleagues to see my private events in the (shared) outlook/exchange calender at work. They have to see when I am not available but for private events they must not see WHY I am not available and what kind of private event that is.

How can I

1. create a private event in iCal that
   when synched with my phone an later
   also with outlook is still marked as
   private,
2. see in iCal whether something is marked as private?

Has anyone figured out a workflow for this scenario? Maybe using something else than The Missing Sync or some plugin (preferably without pushing anything to the cloud)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the iPhone. Events can be marked a private from OS X only.